# What is the internal difference between these two modes when getting the psnr value using ffmpg?

Tags: ffmpeg, metrics

1. Option:  -psnr as H264 parameter

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf -codec:v libx264 -psnr -f mp4 -b:v 100k -pass 1 output.mp4

---

2. Option : Comparing input and output with the psnr filter.

ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf -codec:v libx264 -f mp4 -b:v 100k -pass 1 output.mp4
ffmpeg -i output.mp4 -i input.mp4 -filter_complex psnr -f null –

Answer (score 0):

The CLI switch `-psnr` instructs the encoder to calculate PSNR, so it is useful to get PSNR for the current encoding session and only the current encoding session.

The `psnr` filter is used to calculate the value between two pre-encoded streams, and cannot be used to calculate for encoding happening in the same command.